# fetch webhook data in POST request and then use this data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

in my nextjs app when a user completed an order there is a webhook that posts to my api route `/hook`

I'm looking for a way to get this data into my app, I just need the info once and then it can be discarded.

I have tried to push the data into an array and then I would make a GET request in my app to fetch once it exists but my array is always showing as empty. There is probably a better way to do this?

Ideally I don't want to store in a db as this is not required.

How can I use the POST data inside of my react/nextjs app?

**webhook**

```
{summary: {
  subtotal: 8.99,
  taxableTotal: 8.99,
  total: 11.46,
  payableNow: 11.46,   
}
```

**server.js**

```
 export default async (req, res) => {
    
    const arr = []
    console.log(arr)
  const { method, body } = req
    if (method === 'POST')
      {
        res.statusCode = 200
     
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            'msg' : body,
          
        }))  
        console.log(body)
        arr.push(JSON.stringify({body}))
      } else {
        // res.statusCode = 200
        // res.json(arr)
        res.status(200).json(arr)
      }
}
```

Comment: your array seems to be defined locally isn't it ?

Comment: yes this is defined in my server.js file, I wanted to store the post data in this array and  then use it in the get request

Comment: from what you posted your array is defined inside your request handler, just move it to the upper scope (module file I guesss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your array part of the module scope instead of creating it inside your request handler (which will create one array per request)

```js
const arr = []

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method, body } = req
    if (method === 'POST')
      {
        res.statusCode = 200
     
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            'msg' : body,
          
        }))  
        arr.push(JSON.stringify({body}))
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(arr)
      }
}
```